# Информация по Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интеграция

Какую информацию лучше всего собрать по Битриксу для разработчика, что работает в основном с 1С, перед тем как дать ему задание для их интеграции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Битрикс-разработчик, должен обладать информацией (в том или ином объёме) по всем курсам. Для интеграции с 1С советую посмотреть курсы:

- Администратор. Базовый (Понимание инфоблоков)
- Администратор. Бизнес
- Разработчик Bitrix Framework

Лучше всего, чтобы интеграцию выполняли 2 специалиста - 1С-программист и разработчик по Битрикс. Если всё должен выполнить 1 программист, то быстрее и проще начать с практики:

- Создать бэкап 1С;
- Поднять тестовую/локальную копию сайта;
- Настроить стандартную интеграцию по официальной документации.
  А дальше уже решать вопросы по мере их появления.

Курсы: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php

Интеграция с 1С: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=1158

Протокол обмена с сайтом: http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/

Также у Битрикс есть замечательная бесплатная служба поддержки, где гарантированно отвечают на заданный вопрос в установленные сроки и помогают их решить.
http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/support/customers/ticket.php?show_wizard=Y

Comment: А что если его задача будет заключаться лишь в интеграции? Какая-то иная информация еще понадобится? Помимо перечисленного, тех. требований?

Comment: Проще всего поставить тестовый сайт и провести пробную интеграцию. На сайте создадутся инфоблоки и загрузятся элементы. Если сайт уже существующий и рабочий - то вполне возможно, что структура инфоблоков и элементов, которая создастся будет отличаться от той, которая уже настроена на сайте. Потребуется корректировка оформления, возможно настройка инфоблоков. Также могут всплыть разные ньюансы - например с комплектами, ценами, цветами и т.п., которые не укладываются в схему стандартной интеграции. Для этого может потребоваться знание API Битрикс.